# `Select column from returned row from class

Tags: php

hi im trying to remove all my old globals from my old procedural code and im stuck on one that calls the current user. 
The global is set on login and then used everywhere, so instead on login i set a token in database with a hashed cookie and intend to call the row that way but cant seem to get it working in a class.
Any help would be much appreciated bit of a noob with class objects

this works without class
test.php

```
    // works 
    $res = DB::run("SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN groups ON users.class=groups.group_id WHERE token=? AND users.enabled='yes' AND users.status = 'confirmed'", [$_COOKIE['pass']]);
    $row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // removed global $GLOBALS["CURUSER"] = $row;

    echo $row["id"];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $row["username"];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $row["password"];
    echo '<br>';
```

now if i put it in a class & controller it does not work
Test.php

```
class Test extends Controller {

    public function __construct(){
      $this->userModel = $this->model('User');
    }

    public function index()
    {
dbconn();
stdhead('User');
    $row = $this->userModel->getCurrentUser();

    echo $row["id"];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $row["username"];
    echo '<br>';
    echo $row["password"];
    echo '<br>';
stdfoot();
}
}
```

User.php

```
<?php
  class User {
    private $db;

    public function __construct(){
      $this->db = new Database;
    }

    // get current user
    public function getCurrentUser(){
    $res = db->run("SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN groups ON users.class=groups.group_id WHERE token=? AND users.enabled='yes' AND users.status = 'confirmed'", [$_COOKIE['pass']]);
    $row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $row;
    }
}
```

Comment: `this` is a keyword only usable within a class. You should reference the variable you created (`$row`) instead.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out that was just an example my code is in a class controller i should of mentioned that if updated the code